# I'm going to see a doctor tomorrow

Tags: future

Could you please tell me whether the sentences below mean the same to you?

Group A:

1. I'm going to play basketball tomorrow.
2. I'm playing basketball tomorrow.
3. I'll be playing basketball tomorrow.

Group B:

4. I'm going to see a doctor tomorrow.
5. I'm seeing a doctor tomorrow.
6. I'll be seeing a doctor tomorrow.

Comment: Expressing the Future in English -  https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-expressing-the-future.htm

Comment: They mean the same thing to me.